# How to Justify-End only select Nav-Items in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to float only select nav-items to the right with *.justify-content-end*

This works fine if I add it to the top level div class but if I create a special div with isolating one nav-items and use that class it does not work:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bewander</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href='@Url.Action("Create", "Reviews")'>Write a Review </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Reviews")'>Search the World</a>
            </li>
            <div class="justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href='@Url.Action("Login", "Account")'>Login</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

While .justify-content-end works this way, it moves all the items which I do not want, hence me trying to Isolate the specific nav-item:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bewander</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href='@Url.Action("Create", "Reviews")'>Write a Review </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Reviews")'>Search the World</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href='@Url.Action("Login", "Account")'>Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Here is a codepen to test on](https://codepen.io/craigvantonder/pen/MJwLWb?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.justify-content-end` pushes the `.navbar-nav` to the end since it's the only child.

Instead, you can try forcing the `.navbar-nav` to grow to full-width by applying `flex-grow: 1` to it. Then, apply `margin-left: auto;` to the item you want to push to the right. Luckily, bootstrap has a utility class for the latter – `.ml-auto`.

[**Updated Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwoWde)